# apply my knowledge to "improve" or "improving" something?

Tags: word-usage

Which one should I use, improve or improving, in the following example:

> I would like to apply my knowledge to (improve or improving) something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either say:

> I would like to apply my knowledge to improve...

Or you can say:

> I would like to apply my knowledge toward improving...

The two statements are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

"Improve" is correct in this sentence. It is in the present tense and is considered present progressive, I think. It implies a continuous, ongoing action. That is, you are going to do the action (improving something) both in the present and future.